# WKWebView - Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ios, json, wkwebview

I trying to read my local JSON file on IOS WKWebview. However Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I'm using UIWebview before and it's work fine. However when i change to WKWebview this error happen.

```
 $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
            url: 'json_app/country_state_json.json?callback=?',
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json) 
            {},
            error: function(e) {}
        });
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, at this point WKWebView does not handle JavaScript asynchronously loading files using the "file://" protocol [[1](http://blogging.alastair.is/the-disappointing-reality-of-wkwebview/)][[2](http://www.openradar.me/18039024)].  It works when the files are loaded from the DOM, just not using ajax or jQuery's .get (which is just abstracted ajax).

Here's a hack that I am simultaneously proud of and not proud of:

I have an app that needs to load a JSON object based on some dynamic information and then process it to display the web content.  Originally, I was trying to have the JavaScript get the JSON file dynamically:

The old HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="makeContent.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

The old JSON:

```
{
    "myData": true,
    ...
}
```

The old JavaScript:

```
$.get("data.json", function (data) {
  // Process the data and generate the content
}, "json");
```

With this, I was encountering the same problem that you were.  WKWebView would not load the data.json file.

My hack was to include the JSON content as another JavaScript object that is included in the DOM.  The new JavaScript script simply assigns the JSON data as a string into a global variable.  Note that this string needs to be a single line, as JavaScript doesn't support multiline strings.  Then, this new script is dynamically inserted into the DOM when the WKWebView loads:

JavaScript Data file (replaces the JSON file):

```
var data = '{ "myData": true, ... }';
```

Swift:

```
let jsonInsertion = "var node = document.createElement('script');" +
                    "node.setAttribute('src', 'data.js');" +
                    "node.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');" +
                    "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];" +
                    "head.insertBefore(node, head.childNodes[0]);"
webView?.evaluateJavaScript(jsonInsertion, completionHandler:  { (_, error) in
    print(error)
})
```

The resulting HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="makeContent.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Now, your JavaScript should be able to access the data as a global variable, and convert it using JSON.parse(data).  You might need to add some synchronization code to ensure that your script runs *after* the data script is inserted by the app.

Again, this is a hack, but it's working for me.  Hopefully it might be useful to you until Apple allows the "file://" protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that you need to provide a full url in the request instead of a relative one. How about using:

```
url: document.URL + "/json_app/country_state_json.json?callback=",
```

(I removed the trailing `?` - that is not correct and results in a malformed URL)